# error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'cv::Mat&'

Tags: c++, opencv, reference, pass-by-reference, argument-passing

The below is my function prototype.

```
void devectorize(Mat &vec,Mat mask,Mat& img);
```

I am getting the below error when I try to call this function in my code. What would be the reason?

```
Mat V;

for(int i=0;i<V.cols;i++)
{
  devectorize(V.col(i),mask,E_img); //Error in this line
}
```

> ```
> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'cv::Mat&' from an rvalue of type 'cv::Mat'
> utils.h:11:6: error: in passing argument 1 of 'void devectorize(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat, cv::Mat&)'
> ```

Comment: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/

Comment: I re-tagged your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot bind a non-const reference to a temporary. In your case the first argument to devectorize is a non-const reference and the return value from `V.col(i)` is the temporary. This code would work

```
for (int i = 0; i < V.cols; i++)
{
    Mat tmp = V.col(i);
    devectorize(tmp, mask, E_img);
}
```

so would changing the first parameter of devectorize to `const Mat&`.

Comment: You saved my hours. Thank you sir, I owe you one. Great day. I also thank @user2727765 for the question